# Splitting based on particular pattern and editing string

Tags: python, regex, split, pattern-matching

I am trying to split a string based on a particular pattern in an effort to rejoin it later after adding a few characters.

Here's a sample of my string: "123\babc\b:123" which I need to convert to "123\babc\\"b\":123". I need to do it several times in a long string. I have tried variations of the following:

```
regex = r"(\\b[a-zA-Z]+)\\b:"
test_str = "123\\babc\\b:123"
x = re.split(regex, test_str)
```

but it doesn't split at the right positions for me to join. Is there another way of doing this/another way of splitting and joining?

Comment: Can you describe where you want to split it?

Comment: If you just want to replace a sub part of the string, you can have a look at [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: I was trying to split it right before and after the second "b" so that I can use '"'.join(x) to get the required result.

Comment: @AlexandreB. I couldn't figure out how to access just the second 'b' given that the string matched the pattern. It kept replacing both the first and second 'b's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you can do it with `re.split` as suggested. You can split by `\b` and then rebuild your output with a specific separator (and keep the `\b` when you want too).

Here an example:

```
# Import module
import re

string = "123\\babc\\b:123"

# Split by "\n"
list_sliced = re.split(r'\\b', "123\\babc\\b:123")
print(list_sliced)
# ['123', 'abc', ':123']

# Define your custom separator
custom_sep = '\\\\"b\\"'
# Build your new output
output = list_sliced[0]
# Iterate over each word
for i, word in enumerate(list_sliced[1:]):
    # Chose the separator according the parity (since we don't want to change the first "\b")
    sep = "\\\\b"
    if i % 2 ==  1:
        sep = custom_sep
    # Update output
    output += sep + word

print(output)
# 123\\babc\\"b\":123
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the following expression,

```
^([\\]*)([^\\]+)([\\]*)([^\\]+)([\\]*)([^:]+):(.*)$
```

and a replacement of,

```
\1\2\3\4\5\\"\6\\":\7
```

with a `re.sub` might return our desired output.

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/L3AzCJ/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. This works perfectly for the given test string, but doesn't work in case there are other backslashes in the string. For example it doesn't work for test_str = "\\123\\babc\\b:123". I should have been clearer that there can be other characters in the string.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I am using an API to pull a string, which I then need to convert to a Dataframe. I need to add double quotes to certain tags to convert them into the right format.